# Stop after failed QUnit.js test

Tags: javascript, qunit

Is there a way to get `QUnit.js` to not run the remaining tests after a single one fails?

Using the following code as an example:

```
QUnit.test('test1', function(assert) {                 
    assert.equal(1,1);
    assert.equal(1,2);
    assert.equal(3,3);
});              

QUnit.test('test2', function(assert) {                 
    assert.equal(4,4);
    assert.equal(5,5);
    assert.equal(6,6);
});
```

Is there some way to get QUnit to stop executing after the `assert.equal(1,2)`? This means that `test2` should never be run.

Comment: Not that I know of currently, and honestly, it shouldn't matter, right? I mean tests should be idempotent so that one does not affect another. Now, if you just mean for efficiency... still don't know of a way. :)

Comment: Now that I think about it... you could set up a [test "done" callback](http://api.qunitjs.com/QUnit.testDone/), check the name and if there were failures, but then what? Throw an exception?

Comment: If a test fails, I'd like to put it at the start of the file to debug what happens. If every other test runs, then the console output gets polluted making it a pain to debug the first one. That's why it matters to me :)

Comment: @jakerella You wrote it nicely - "should be". But what if you have a module setup method and it fails from a reason (e.g.FuncUnit is based on QUnit and it seems legit that a module setup do an "unpure" action and you do not want continue when the action has failed).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to stop QUnit after test case fail will be

```
QUnit.testDone( function( details ) {
    if (details.failed>0){
        QUnit.config.queue.length = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based on my comments above I ran the code below and things to stop as I think you want them to. Again, as I said in the comments, I would really investigate whether this is a good idea. Generally you want your tests to be idempotent such that any one failure does not affect any other test.

Note that we have to set the `reorder` config option to `false` here, otherwise QUnit will attempt to run the previously failed test first to "short circuit" things, but you don't want that I'm guessing. I also added a "test0" just to see the fill effect.

```
QUnit.config.reorder = false;

// This is how we detect the failure and cancel the rest of the tests...
QUnit.testDone(function(details) {
    console.log(details);
    if (details.name === 'test1' && details.failed) {
        throw new Error('Cannot proceed because of failure in test1!');
    }
});

QUnit.test('test0', function(assert) {                 
    assert.equal(1,1);
    assert.equal(2,2);
    assert.equal(3,3);
});

QUnit.test('test1', function(assert) {                 
    assert.equal(1,1);
    assert.equal(1,2);
    assert.equal(3,3);
});              

QUnit.test('test2', function(assert) {                 
    assert.equal(4,4);
    assert.equal(5,5);
    assert.equal(6,6);
});
```

You won't get any visual feedback that the tests were canceled because this isn't really interacting with the QUnit UI. However, because we threw an `Error` object you can open the developer console and see the output there:

[image]